# How to get Windows Active Directory Username .Net Core

Tags: .net, windows, api, active-directory

I want to get Active Direcory username with .Net Core
I have not an idea for this situation.

Comment: I use IIS and Visual Studio - good luck not using those.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this directly, because Angular is a front-end environment - meaning that it runs in the user's browser. As such, it does not have access to AD, which is presumably running in the server's environment.

You'd have to write server-side code that interacts with AD, and create an API that the client can call to get it.

Comment: I did it and it's works

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

...

// Set up the domain context
using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "yourdomain.local"))
{
    // Find the current user
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, User.Identity.Name);

    if (user != null)
    {
        // Get the user's SAMAccountName
        string username = user.SamAccountName;
    }
}
```

In this code, a new `PrincipalContext` object is created and specified the domain context. Then, the `UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity` method is used to find the current user based on the `User.Identity.Name` property (it should contain the user's Windows username).

If the user is found (`user != null`), you can then retrieve their `SamAccountName` property, which contains their Active Directory username.

Note that you will need to include a reference to the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace for this code to work.